# Is it common practice for an admissions office to ask a transfer student for the current semester's grades?

Tags: undergraduate, transfer-student

I applied to a state university for the Fall semester the first day that applications opened for transfer students.
The admission office wrote that decisions take 8-10 weeks.
After 10 weeks, I emailed the admissions office and they told me they would have an answer in an additional 2 weeks (for a total of 14 weeks from the initial submission date).
Today, 14 weeks after my submission, I emailed them and asked if they had any update since I would have to make living arrangements if I got accepted.

They responded:

> The admission committee reviewed your application and determined we
>   need your spring grades. We will review your application once we get
>   an updated transcript in May or June. Due to limited space
>   availability, it would be helpful to have a back up plan for the fall.

Is it common practice to give students responses in such uncertain terms?
I responded asking if there was anything I can do to speed up the answer (e.g. giving them my current grades) but didn't receive a reply.

I'm not sure that this is relevant, but my GPA is 3.86 (which makes me wonder why they would need to see my grades).

Comment: It sounds like you're on a sort of wait list, and they'll decide whom to accept from the list (if anyone) based on spring grades.

Comment: @user37208 Is it common to given an answer in May/June for a semester starting in September?

Answer (score 1):

It's not so weird.  A lot of places do admissions the week before classes start, or even after classes start.  Only selective universities plan many months ahead.